# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" for user input

Tags: java, integer

Even though I have parsed it to an integer value I'm still getting an error. I need to get the integer value from a String input where I remove the  comma and space, and store it in an array, then I convert that array to an integer array

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class SeriesSolution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         int count = sc.nextInt();
         ArrayList<Integer> modes = new ArrayList<>();
         for (int x = 0; x < count; x++) {
             String lines = sc.nextLine();
             String[] strs = lines.split(", ");
             int[] array = new int[strs.length];
             for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
                 if (Integer.parseInt(strs[i]) > 0 && Integer.parseInt(strs[i]) < 100) {
                     array[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);

                 }
             }
             modes.add(mode(array));
         }
         for (int y:modes){
             System.out.println(y);
         }
     }

     private static int mode(int a[]) {
         int maxValue=0, maxCount=0;

         for (int anA : a) {
             int count = 0;
             for (int anA1 : a) {
                 if (anA1 == anA) ++count;
             }
             if (count > maxCount) {
                 maxCount = count;
                 maxValue = anA;
             }
         }
         return maxValue;
     }
}
```

Comment: The problem I think is with the use of `Scanner` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is mainly because `Scanner` accepts `Enter` keystroke as input. And because of which

`String lines = sc.nextLine();`

this peice of code stores an empty string into `lines` variable. This empty string throws `NumberFormatException` when passed to `parseInt()`

I would recommend you to use `BufferedReader` with `InputStreamReader`

`BufferedReader br = new BuffereedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`

This is good for larger inputs and is error free. Though empty checks are must as prevention is better.

If you want to use `Scanner`, I would recommend you to update the code and use the below snippet of code.

```
String lines = "";
while (lines.equals("")) {
    lines = sc.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a check before the parseInt

```
if (strs[i] != null && !"".equals(strs[i]) && Integer.parseInt(strs[i])  ...
```

Or surround it with a try catch to catch the NumberformatException that will happen if a string is inserted instead of a number

Comment: Saw the updated, and deleted my comment, haha. I would just like good habits to be spread about.

Comment: I think this is only to prevent the `NumberFormatException`, but not the actual cause of the exception.

Comment: Better to use isEmpty() check before parsing